# Convert resultset to table or .sql file in Mysql query browser?

Tags: mysql, sql

In  Mysql query browser i make a resultset in a table by a query ,please let me know that how can i convert this resultset to a .sql file or to a new table?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can run a select query and insert it to table in one [command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
    SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
    FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

if the temp table dont exist you can use [create table ... select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html)

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl SELECT * FROM orig_tbl;
```

Comment: thanks,but please let me know that, creat table must be before insert?

Comment: i use this code but recieve error that new_tb1 does not exist         CREATE TABLE new_tbl SELECT * FROM tbarticles;
INSERT INTO new_tb1 (articleid)
    SELECT tbarticles.articleid
    FROM tbarticles WHERE tbarticles.articleid >= 100;

Comment: you should use only : CREATE TABLE new_tbl SELECT * FROM tbarticles;

Comment: after check this table new_tbl, see if there rows in it. see a typo mistake , you call one time to new_tbl and one time to new_tb1

Comment: yes,sorry i corrected but for fileds in main table that must not be null, i receive error:Field 'articlebody' doesn't have a default value

Comment: and no i can't see row while its name is in list of table.

Comment: can you drop new_tbl , you can create the  new table only with the fields you want. ? after that use the INSERT INTO new_tbl (articleid) SELECT tbarticles.articleid FROM tbarticles WHERE tbarticles.articleid >= 100;

Comment: Thanks a lot,i make this sql and it is ok for making new table which has also content and i can then make .sql file with Mysql administrator---------CREATE TABLE new_tb1 SELECT * FROM tbarticles
WHERE tbarticles.articleid > 100;

Comment: If you have large tables with many fields I would recommend using a tool for this job. It's very easy to make mistakes while transferring large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

According to MySql Query Browser manual I wasn't able to find any import functionality. Only experimental Regex Text importer tool.

Have you tried MySQL Workbench?

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html

It's replacing the old MySQL Query Browser.

From Query Browser manual:

> You can export any result set from
>   MySQL Query Browser by right-clicking
>   within the result set and choosing an
>   option from the EXPORT RESULTSET
>   sub-menu. You can choose to export the
>   result set in CSV, XML, HTML,
>   Microsoft Excel XLS or PLIST formats.

If you need to work with MySQL Query Browser you could think of exporting in CSV and converting it into .sql file using for instance an online tool:

http://www.withdata.com/csv/csv-to-sql/

Comment: Thanks, can i make .sql file with MySQL Workbench ?

Comment: Yes you can. Check the export part from the manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/wb-manage-server-data-dump-tab.html)

Comment: Personally I use Navicat for my db-tasks - really love it. It will cost you some money, but will increase your productivity. Of course you can do almost anything with MySQL syntax scripts, but it's so much faster to use well throught GUI to complete the task.